# when i refresh a tab bar view in flutter app, other tab bar view also refreshing

Tags: flutter

i'm using a tab bar with 4 tabs in my flutter app. first and second tabs have refreshIndicators. when a tab bar view is refreshing, other tab bar view is also refreshing automatically. i want to stop that. please help me

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make refresh only one tab you should make this tab depends on its own properties and data, separated from other's tabs. Hope this helps you. To get a more detailed answer please post your code.